# How to convert text column to datetime MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a script that every five minutes updates the values of the table in MySql server.
The problem is that in one column called 'Date' I have a date and time in text. like this:

```
Date

24/04/2021 08:22:01
24/04/2021 08:22:02
24/04/2021 08:22:03
...
```

I want to be able to convert that into a datetime so I can then manage the max or min date. I have seen a lot of topics talking about this, but they all are in SQL and not MySql.

Comment: Use `STR_TO_DATE()` function with proper pattern.

Comment: Do you want to convert the values to DATETIME on insert or when querying the data? Check out `STR_TO_DATE` (https://www.sqlines.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date)

Comment: But in the syntax asks for a string and i want to convert all the column, how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (`Date` VARCHAR(255));
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> ('24/04/2021 08:22:01'),
> ('24/04/2021 08:22:02'),
> ('24/04/2021 08:22:03');
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> | Date                |
> | :------------------ |
> | 24/04/2021 08:22:01 |
> | 24/04/2021 08:22:02 |
> | 24/04/2021 08:22:03 |
> ```

> ```
> -- variant 1 - transform in a query
> SELECT `date`, STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d\/%c\/%Y %H:%i:%s') formatted_date
> FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> date                | formatted_date     
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 24/04/2021 08:22:01 | 2021-04-24 08:22:01
> 24/04/2021 08:22:02 | 2021-04-24 08:22:02
> 24/04/2021 08:22:03 | 2021-04-24 08:22:03
> ```

> ```
> -- variant 2 - create generated column
> ALTER TABLE test 
>   ADD COLUMN formatted_date DATETIME AS (STR_TO_DATE(`date`, '%d\/%c\/%Y %H:%i:%s')) STORED;
> SELECT * FROM test;
> ```
>
> ```
> Date                | formatted_date     
> :------------------ | :------------------
> 24/04/2021 08:22:01 | 2021-04-24 08:22:01
> 24/04/2021 08:22:02 | 2021-04-24 08:22:02
> 24/04/2021 08:22:03 | 2021-04-24 08:22:03
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f52fc74d5c36d6b9bd2d48949353326d)*

Comment: The formatted_date is not being created in variant 2 and in variant one the formatted_date is returning null in this values (06/03/2020 20:49:05),(20/04/2021 18:57:07)...

Comment: Can you tell me why a update set column doesnt work ? its telling me that it worked but the dtype doesnt change ...

Comment: @Ricardoke *formatted_date is returning null* Sorry, misprint. Fixed. *its telling me that it worked but the dtype doesnt change* Show precise query text. Also tell the amount of rows to be processed and what is the table on-disk size.